# How can I add admin user using OnModelCreating in ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

How can I add admin user using `OnModelCreating` in ASP.NET Identity?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>
    (
       user.UserName = "admin";
       user.Email = "admin@gmail.com";
       string userPassword = "Admin123#";
    ).ToTable("AspNetUsers");
}
```

Comment: u have to provide all the mandatory fields

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // any unique string id
        const string ADMIN_ID = "a18be9c0-aa65-4af8-bd17-00bd9344e575";
        const string ROLE_ID = "ad376a8f-9eab-4bb9-9fca-30b01540f445";

        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(new IdentityRole
        {
            Id = ROLE_ID,
            Name = "admin",
            NormalizedName = "admin"
        });

        var hasher = new PasswordHasher<IdentityUser>();
        builder.Entity<IdentityUser>().HasData(new IdentityUser
        {
            Id = ADMIN_ID,
            UserName = "admin",
            NormalizedUserName = "admin",
            Email = "admin@gmail.com",
            NormalizedEmail = "admin@gmail.com",
            EmailConfirmed = false,
            PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword(null, "Admin123#"),
            SecurityStamp = string.Empty
        });

        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().HasData(new IdentityUserRole<string>
        {
            RoleId = ROLE_ID,
            UserId = ADMIN_ID
        });
    }
```

Reference :

https://inneka.com/programming/c/how-to-seed-an-admin-user-in-ef-core-2-1-0/

Answer (score 3):

> How can I add admin user using OnModelCreating in ASP.NET Identity?

**You don't do it in this method**.

The documentation for OnModelCreating states:

> Typically, this method is called only once when the first instance of a derived context is created.

This is for when the *Context* is created, not when any defined typed dbset on the context is created.

If you want to change an object before it is sent to the database, there are other Posts that have that answer.

[How to create new entity object, modify it in Model before SaveChanges()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932148/how-to-create-new-entity-object-modify-it-in-model-before-savechanges)